# Creating image border with image JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have to do a TV screen using Scenebulider in JavaFX. I got to the point where I two images overlaps together and we can both of them but border image should be rounded and normal border should be visible too. The first photo is what I already have, and the second one is how it should look. It's stackpane in a stackpane.

What I have:
[image: What I have]

how it should look:
[image: how it should look]

```css
.backgorund{/*main stackpane*/

    -fx-background-image: url("drewno.jpg");

}



.test{/*stackpane within stackpane*/

    -fx-background-image:url(szum.jpg);
    -fx-border-image-source: url(drewno.jpg);
    -fx-border-image-width: 50, 100;
    -fx-border-image-slice: 50, 20;
    -fx-border-width:60,110;
    -fx-border-color: black;


}
```

[drewno2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f61Ah.jpg)

[szum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7qPp.jpg)

Comment: I am guessing that you should just add both images to a single `StackPane`. What does the second image look like?

Comment: I did that, both of them are in the same stackpane, and still no result. Two images are simple .jpg without any cuts

Comment: Post the two images you are using.

Comment: added to main post

Comment: I am confused now. How are you expecting to get the second image with the two images you have? Seems like you are missing the metal border image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple approach would be putting the screen behind the "border" and making sure the "border image" is transparent where the screen should be shown (requires image type supporting transparency, e.g. png).

You could however also put the screen on top of the background an apply a `Shape` covering the area where the screen should be visible as `clip`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    ImageView border = new ImageView("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/wood-texture-plank-background_1372-642.jpg");
    ImageView screen = new ImageView("https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1137709/thumb/9.jpg");
    border.setFitWidth(500);
    border.setFitHeight(500);
    screen.setFitWidth(400);
    screen.setFitHeight(400);

    Path clip = new Path(new MoveTo(50, 400), new ArcTo(50, 200, 0, 50, 0, false, true), new HLineTo(350), new ArcTo(50, 200, 0, 350, 400, false, true), new ClosePath());
    clip.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    clip.setStroke(null);
    screen.setClip(clip);

    StackPane root = new StackPane(border, screen);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

You could also produce this result via fxml but afaik SceneBuilder does not allow you to add/edit a clip:

```xml
<ImageView>
    <image>
        ...
    <image>
    <clip>
        <Path fill="BLACK">
            <elements>
                <MoveTo x="50" y="400" />
                <ArcTo radiusX="50" radiusY="200" x="50" sweep="true" />
                <HLineTo x="350" />
                <ArcTo radiusX="50" radiusY="200" x="350" y="400" sweep="true" />
                <ClosePath />
            </elements>
        </Path>
    /clip>
<ImageView>
```

You probably need to modify the clip path a bit to look exactly the way you want...

Comment: I understand how it works now, but is there any way to do it by css? With your implementaion, but it's would be pretty hard to do with media(later stage of that task)

Comment: No the `clip` property cannot be assigned via CSS. You'd be better off using the first approach (i.e. using a image manipulation program to "cut out" a transparent area in the "border"). Since `MediaView` is a subclass of `Node` you can use it's `clip` property the same way I used it with `ImageView` in the code snippet.